# Jquery mouseover mouseout menu using setTimeout

Tags: jquery, menu, mouseover, settimeout, mouseout

Can someone help me with this simple code.. I'm still a noob on js and I don't know what im doing wrong. Basically Im trying to make a mouseover menu.

```
function showQuickLinks() {
//show the menu
}
function hideQuickLinks() {
//hides the menu
}

//button mouseover
$("#quick-links-dd").mouseover(function() { 
 showQuickLinks();
});

var mnuTimeout;

//clears timeout when it rolls over the button
$("#quick-links-dd").mouseover(function () {        
   clearTimeout(mnuTimeout);    
})

//$("#quick-links) - quick links container
//hides the menu when the mouse is not over the container
$("#quick-links").mouseout(function () {
  mnuTimeout = setTimeout("hideQuickLinks()",1000);
});
```

The mouse over works but it doesn't execute the code when the mouse is outside the link container.

Comment: First of all, don't pass a string to setTimeout. Yes it's legal but is considered bad practice by most. Instead pass a function reference: `setTimeout(hideQuickLinks,1000)`. Treat the first argument of setTimeout exactly the same way you're treating the first argument to jquery's mouseover and mouseout methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var mnuTimeout = null;

$(function() { 
   $("#quick-links-dd").hover() {
       clearTimeout(mnuTimeout);
       showQuickLinks();
   }, function() {  
      mnuTimeout = setTimeout(hideQuickLinks,1000);
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you missing a " ?

```
("#quick-links").mouseout(function () {
  mnuTimeout = setTimeout("hideQuickLinks()",1000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had intermittent issues with lost onmouseout events. My eventual solution was to add mouseover events to surrounding elements, and have them also cancel the popup.